# Publishing mosaic dataset to image service

Tags: arcgis-server, image-service, publishing, mosaic-dataset

I'm having problems publishing a mosaic dataset to an image service. While I can publish a service, the result does not carry over the pixel values (every cell is valued at 1.134274E+38). Strangely enough, the thumbnail image in arcCatalog shows the correct image, not sure why I can't visualize it any other way.

Some specifics about my mosaic dataset: 
it has a time dimension, 
contains 12 rasters,
1488 x 802 grid/ single band,
spatial reference: Albers equal area (projected),
pixel type: floating point,
I have ArcGIS Image Extension installed,
I didn't register the underlying data, instead transferring everything (12 rasters) to the server

I've included some screen shots of the process I went through (see below).  Too many steps involved for someone to 'spot' a problem, probably.  I just want to see if someone has had a similar issue and what they did about it. Also, if someone has found a useful guide, I'd love to hear about it. I had used: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Publishing_image_services/01540000045v000000/

screen shots: 
What I began with in mxd[image: What I began with in an mxd]

Making the image service through Arc Catalog
[image: Making the image service through Arc Catalog]
Correct image appears in catalog thumbnail[image: correct image appears in catalog thumbnail]
results not carrying over to preview, services or mxd[image]

Comment: I was curious about why my ending statement, 'thanks for your time', was removed.  Can someone please fill me in - was I asking something rude?  Was I assuming people's involvement?  Seemed like a polite thing to say at the time.

Comment: I would guess that the ending statement was possibly removed because it was irrelevant to obtaining an answer and likely was removed to fulfill an edit restriction where I believe at least 6 characters must be changed.  The editor likely only had a small correction and couldn't find anything else to change.

Comment: Check this comment and report back.  If successful, answer your own question with what you did.  
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98374#comment-237931
Plus have you tried running the analyse on your Mosaic Dataset?

Answer (score 1):

How is your original raster pixel depth? Are they 32 bit flaot? Make sure your mosaic dataset is compatible with these raster and they are same with each other.
unfortunately i cannot see your screenshots. but according to you told, i recommend you to try publishing as registering data even if it doesn't solve the problem.